# Sharepoint 2013 search - How can we hide promoted results/best bets for a particular search results page

Tags: search, sharepoint

How can we hide promoted results for a particular search results page. This page shows results from a particular list and I do not want to show best bets on this page which are from other location.

Answer (score 0):

If you check out this reference:
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Change-settings-for-the-Search-Results-Web-Part-40ff85b3-bc5e-4230-b1dd-f088188e487e

you will see that Promoted Results is an option you can turn off in the Results Settings of the Search Results WebPart.